# Bulletproof method for dealing with duplicate runs

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

I have a script at my router running every 30 minutes by cron. Router ocassionally runs it twice, few seconds apart but only when the router is booting. Few weeks ago, to avoid it being run twice simoultaneously, I used pidof to check, intentionally avoiding any filelock method - to prevent any possible problems.

```
for pid in $(pidof DoubleDDNS); do
  if [ $pid != $$ ]; then
    echo "DoubleDDNS [no2run] Exiting"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

But. I just had a problem. For some reason, the router went bizzrk. My script did not finish, apprantly. Got stuck in the memory forever. So, the above check prevented my script to run again while the original (older) run did not finish its job. That created a problem (not reporting a new WAN IP address to DDNS).

I do not think it is my script's fault as there are no commands in it that could get it stuck. The script runs for 8+ months on several routers with no problem at all. It is well written, handling and testing for all possible errors. The router mostly worked, but many things in it were broken (e.g. ssl). Router did not report any of its 3 memories as filled (which may or may not be true). It would not even reset when I selected reset in its own WebGUI and had to be reset with the on/off button!

So, how do I bulletproof my check for second run? I am thinking: include a check if previous instance was running for more than 60 seconds, and if so, it would

1. try to kill any old instance
2. continue despite being duplicate run. Script runs on 3rd and 33rd minutes of every hour and single run lasts <15 seconds.

Questions (preferably without any file generation, but maybe my avoidance of filelock was a bad solution, so advise):

1. How to detect how old is the previous run?
2. Any better ideas than mine?
3. is there a way to suicide a script: if script not finished in 60 seconds, kill this script instance

Keep in mind: router, sh and busybox. So, a limited set of things are available. Asus routers Router Asus RT-AC*U are used with Merlin fw.

Comment: `timeout 60s yourscript` would be an easy way to help ensure the script does not linger.

Comment: Or, if `timeout` is for some reason not available, `(yourscript & sleep 60; kill -0 $! && kill $!)`.

Comment: timeout is a no go. But, luckily for me,  DopeGhoti gave me a perfectly usable suicide pill. If I call my script with his version instead of normally, it commits suicide perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a mockup of my working bulletproof version. It is rigged to show logic. It runs on my router OK.

```
#!/bin/sh

age_max_sec=50

LOCKFILE=lock.txt
if [ -e ${LOCKFILE} ]; then
    echo "lockfile exists"
    if kill -0 `cat ${LOCKFILE}`; then
        echo "script runs in mem" 
        lock_date=`date -r ${LOCKFILE} +%s`
        now=`date +%s`
        lock_age=$(($now-$lock_date))
        if [ $lock_ag e -gt $age_max_sec ]; then
            echo "DoubleDDNS (no2runKILL)"
            kill `cat ${LOCKFILE}`
        else
            echo "DoubleDDNS (no2runOK), age $lock_age seconds, quit this run"
            exit 1
        fi   
    else
        echo "not allready running, go ahead"
    fi
fi

echo "working on"

# overkill???? just in case, scorched earth check.
filename=${0##*/}
for pid in $(pidof $filename); do
    if [ $pid != $$ ]; then
        echo "DoubleDDNS (no3runKILL)"
        kill -9 $pid
    fi
done

# make sure the lockfile is removed when we exit and then claim it
trap "rm -f ${LOCKFILE}; exit" INT TERM EXIT
echo $$ > ${LOCKFILE}

# main program here

rm -f ${LOCKFILE}

echo "done"
```

I think I must use lockfile if I want to check age of previous run. So, make a lockfile with pid. If lockfile is not older than set limit of seconds, quit. If it is older, kill previous instance. On my router, I do not have any better ways available for checks I made.

Do i need scorched earth check or is it an overkill? After legitimate lockfile checks are done, I am rechecking if there is lingering but broken process still in the memory and kill if found. Problem is: I do not have a way to test it until eventaually an actual disaster strikes again and regular cleanup does not manage to clean it. If not an overkill...

It should be noted that the availability of the NTP service may influence timed locks and suicide pill. E.g. my first run of the above script would occur about 4 seconds before NTP fixes the time. So, we should take such things into consieration.

Suicide pill provided above by DopeGhoti works perfectly. So, now is just a matter of judging which combo to use. Or all of them? Lockfile, timed release, scorched earth and suicide. Hmm, sounds like overkill but I do not see any of them working against eny other but in perfect (paranoid) harmony. Comments are welcome.